# Apache nutch error NoClassDefFoundError "com/google/protobuf/Message"

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3 with hadoop 1.2.1 and hbase 0.94. I have configured apache nutch for distributed mode. When I run crawling, It gives following error

```
15/12/21 12:06:56 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node1/1.11.1.2:2181, sessionid = 0x151ba038ac60250, negotiated timeout = 180000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/Message
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable.<clinit>(HbaseObjectWritable.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Invocation.write(Invocation.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.sendParam(HBaseClient.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:127)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:115)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:163)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.Message
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

In lib of nutch, there is a jar of protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar 
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add protobuf-java{version}.jar to hadoop lib directory. It should solve your problem.
For classpath verification. Run following command

```
hadoop classpath |grep protobuf
```

If it contains repective jar then it means it has been added to classpath.